# Como criar um comando sql de Update incremental

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Possuo uma tabela `Estoque` onde hoje já existem inúmeras linhas de registros já cadastrados, como posso fazer um Update incremental para preencher uma coluna que adicionei a tabela agora?

```
Produto | N_Serie | Etiqueta
    A   |   123   |   NULL
    B   |   456   |   NULL
    C   |   789   |   NULL
    D   |   101   |   NULL
    E   |   112   |   NULL
    F   |   131   |   NULL
```

Minha necessidade é que o comando faça com que a coluna `Etiqueta` seja preenchida de forma incremental para que no fim fique assim:

```
Produto | N_Serie | Etiqueta
    A   |   123   |    1
    B   |   456   |    2
    C   |   789   |    3
    D   |   101   |    4
    E   |   112   |    5
    F   |   131   |    6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acredito que possa ser feito assim:

Cria uma tabela temporária, utilizando a função row_number() para numerar as linhas.

Dê um update na tabela estoque, selecionando o número sequencial da tabela temporária.

Segue código:

```
with temp as (
select 
Produto, 
N_Serie, 
Row_number() over(order by Produto asc) as linha
from estoque )

update estoque set etiqueta = (select t.linha from temp t where t.produto = estoque.produto and t.n_serie = estoque.n_serie );
```

Funções Postgresql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html

Comment: Eu preciso selecionar todas as colunas da tabela original para criar essa tabela temporária?

Comment: acredito que não, apenas as chaves

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: por nada, disponha

Answer (score 1):

Que tal utilizar um campo do tipo `BIGSERIAL`:

Criação da tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE Estoque
(
    produto TEXT,
    n_serie BIGINT,
    etiqueta BIGSERIAL
);
```

Inserção dos dados:

```
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'A', 123 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'B', 456 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'C', 789 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'D', 101 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'E', 112 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'F', 131 );
```

Teste:

```
SELECT produto, n_serie, etiqueta FROM Estoque;
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso de dados já existentes, sugiro a criação de uma `SEQUENCE` e a inclusão de um valor `DEFAULT` na coluna `etiqueta` apontando para o seu próximo valor `nextval()`:

Tabela Original:

```
CREATE TABLE Estoque
(
    produto TEXT,
    n_serie BIGINT,
    etiqueta BIGINT
);
```

Dados pré-existentes:

```
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'A', 123 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'B', 456 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'C', 789 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'D', 101 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'E', 112 );
INSERT INTO Estoque ( produto, n_serie ) VALUES ( 'F', 131 );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criação da `SEQUENCE`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqEstoque START 1;
```

Ajuste do valor `DEFAULT` do campo `etiqueta`:

```
ALTER TABLE Estoque ALTER COLUMN etiqueta SET DEFAULT nextval('seqEstoque');
```

Atualização dos dados pré-existentes (`UPDATE`):

```
UPDATE Estoque SET etiqueta = nextval('seqEstoque');
```

Teste:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que como as linhas já estão preenchidas eu preciso que seja um Update mesmo nessa coluna nova

Comment: @R.Santos Segue edição

Comment: Boa ideia também +1

Answer (score 0):

No MSSQL, eu utilizaria o comando row_number, conforme o exemplo abaixo. Tente dessa forma ou algum comando parecido na sua versão do SQL

```
create table #Temp1 (Produto varchar(1), N_Serie int, Etiqueta  int)

insert #Temp1
values
   ('A'   ,   123   ,    null ),
   ('B'   ,   456   ,    null ),
   ('C'   ,   789   ,    null ),
   ('D'   ,   101   ,    null ),
   ('E'   ,   112   ,    null ),
   ('F'   ,   131   ,    null )

-- ==================
-- Exibindo o resultado do insert
-- ==================

select * from #Temp1

-- ==================
-- Criando a nova Temp
-- ==================
select Produto, N_Serie, Row_number() over(order by Produto asc) as linha
       into #NovaTabela
  from #Temp1

update a
   set a.Etiqueta = b.linha
  from #Temp1 a 
  join #NovaTabela b on a.Produto = b.Produto

-- ==================
-- Conferindo o resultado
-- ==================
select * from #Temp1
```